# db design for storing inventory per customer

Tags: sql-server, database-design, query-performance

We have a product microservice which stores drugs and we have an inventory microservice that stores inventory for that product.

inventory

| id | productid | quantity on hand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 3 | 10 |

One of the new requirements is to store inventory for patients.

What would be the best practice to accommodate such a case?

Should we just add a new column, `patientid`, to the inventory table or is there better way to handle this?

Adding a new column to the same table will lead to a case where 2 or more rows, one with `patientid` null and other rows that have `patientid` value.  This will lead us to chang all existing db calls to fetch data based on context (`patientid`).

| id | productid | patientid | qoh |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | p1 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | p2 | 10 |
| 3 | 3 | null | 10 |

One of the suggestions from my team member is create new product for each patient owned item. eg

product table

| productid | patient-drug | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john-tylenol | 10mg, |
| 2 | ram-tylenol | 10mg |
| 3 | tylenol | 10 mg |

And then we'd use those patient specific and non-patient specific product IDs in the inventory table to store quantity-on-hand.  However, this approach seems weird due to so many copies of `tylenol` being created.

Answer (score 4):

I would create a table to hold the inventory, along with a separate table to hold patient's on-hand inventory.

This is best described using a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve).

First, we'll create the tables we need.  I'm doing this in `tempdb` to avoid conflicting with objects you may have created already.

```
USE tempdb;

--clean up so we can run this multiple times with changes
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.[UpdatePatientInventory];
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.[Inventory_Balances];
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.[Inventory], dbo.[Patient_Product_OnHand], dbo.[Patient], dbo.[Product], dbo.[TransactionTypes];
GO
```

```
--details about each product
CREATE TABLE dbo.[Product]
(
    [ProductId]         int                 NOT NULL
        IDENTITY(1,1)
        CONSTRAINT [Product_pk]
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
    , [ProductName]     varchar(100)        NOT NULL
);
```

```
--details about each patient
CREATE TABLE dbo.[Patient]
(
    [PatientId]         int                 NOT NULL
        IDENTITY(1,1)
        CONSTRAINT [Patients_pk]
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
    , [PatientName]     varchar(100)        NOT NULL
);
```

```
--Describes the types of transaction entries
CREATE TABLE dbo.[TransactionTypes]
(
    [TransactionTypeId] int                 NOT NULL
        IDENTITY(1,1)
        CONSTRAINT [TransactionTypes_pk]
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
    , [TypeName]        varchar(100)        NOT NULL
);
```

```
--contains multiple transactional rows for each drug added to inventory, or 
--removed from inventory, or transferred to a patient
CREATE TABLE dbo.[Inventory]
(
    [InventoryId]       int                 NOT NULL
        IDENTITY(1,1)
        CONSTRAINT [Inventory_pk]
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
    , [ProductId]       int                 NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [Inventory_Product_fk]
        FOREIGN KEY
        REFERENCES dbo.[Product]([ProductId])
    , [TransactionTypeId]   int             NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [Inventory_TransactionTypeId_fk]
        FOREIGN KEY
        REFERENCES dbo.[TransactionTypes]([TransactionTypeId])
    , [TransactionDate] datetimeoffset(3)   NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [Inventory_tx_date]
        DEFAULT ((SYSUTCDATETIME()))
    , [Quantity]        int                 NOT NULL
);
```

```
--transactions in/out of patients custody
CREATE TABLE dbo.[Patient_Product_OnHand]
(
    [PatientId]         int                 NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [Patient_Product_OnHand_PatientId_fk]
        FOREIGN KEY
        REFERENCES dbo.[Patient]([PatientId])
    , [ProductId]       int                 NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [Patient_Product_OnHand_ProductId_fk]
        FOREIGN KEY
        REFERENCES dbo.[Product]([ProductId])
    , [TransactionDate] datetimeoffset(3)   NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [Patient_Product_OnHand_tx_date]
        DEFAULT ((SYSUTCDATETIME()))
    , [Quantity]        int                 NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT [Patient_Product_OnHand_pk]
        PRIMARY KEY
        NONCLUSTERED
        ([PatientId], [ProductId])
    , INDEX [Patient_Product_OnHand_cx] 
        CLUSTERED 
        ([TransactionDate], [PatientId], [ProductId])
);
GO
```

Here we're inserting some rows of data into each table.

```
--insert some test values
INSERT INTO dbo.[Product] ([ProductName])
VALUES ('Acetominophen')
    , ('Acetylsalicylic Acid');

INSERT INTO dbo.[Patient] ([PatientName])
VALUES ('Sally')
    , ('John');

INSERT INTO dbo.[TransactionTypes] ([TypeName])
VALUES ('Product Received')
    , ('Product Sold')
    , ('Product Assigned to Patient');

INSERT INTO dbo.Inventory ([ProductId], [Quantity], [TransactionDate], [TransactionTypeId])
VALUES (1, 12, '2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', 1)
    , (2, 6, '2021-01-02T12:34:56.789Z', 1);
```

This is what the inventory looks like now:

```
SELECT i.[InventoryId]
    , p.[ProductName]
    , i.[Quantity]
    , i.[TransactionDate]
    , [Transaction Type] = tt.[TypeName]
FROM dbo.[Inventory] i
    INNER JOIN dbo.[Product] p ON i.[ProductId] = p.[ProductId]
    INNER JOIN dbo.[TransactionTypes] tt ON i.[TransactionTypeId] = tt.[TransactionTypeId]
GO
```

| InventoryId | ProductName | Quantity | TransactionDate | Transaction Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Acetominophen | 12 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 +00:00 | Product Received |
| 2 | Acetylsalicylic Acid | 6 | 2021-01-02 12:34:56.789 +00:00 | Product Received |

I'm using a stored procedure to perform transfers between our inventory, and patient's custody:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[UpdatePatientInventory]
(
      @PatientId        int
    , @ProductId        int
    , @TransactionDate  datetimeoffset(3)   = NULL
    , @Quantity         int
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    IF @TransactionDate IS NULL 
    BEGIN
        SET @TransactionDate = SYSUTCDATETIME();
    END
    DECLARE @msg        nvarchar(1000);

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO dbo.Patient_Product_OnHand ([PatientId], [ProductId], [TransactionDate], [Quantity])
        VALUES (@PatientId, @ProductId, @TransactionDate, @Quantity);

        INSERT INTO dbo.Inventory ([ProductId], [TransactionDate], [Quantity], [TransactionTypeId])
        VALUES (@ProductId, @TransactionDate, 0 - @Quantity, 3);

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @msg = ERROR_MESSAGE() + N' at line ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), ERROR_LINE());
        RAISERROR (@msg, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        SET @msg = N'Transaction rolled back.';
        RAISERROR (@msg, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Moving product into patient's custody looks like:

```
EXEC dbo.UpdatePatientInventory @PatientId = 1, @ProductId = 1, @Quantity = 4;
```

This view shows the current inventory, with transactional details and balances at every stage:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.[Inventory_Balances]
AS
SELECT p.[ProductName]
    , i.[TransactionDate]
    , [Transaction Type] = tt.[TypeName]
    , [Transaction Quantity] = i.[Quantity]
    , [Balance] = SUM(i.[Quantity]) OVER (PARTITION BY i.[ProductId] ORDER BY i.[TransactionDate] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
FROM dbo.[Inventory] i
    INNER JOIN dbo.[TransactionTypes] tt ON i.[TransactionTypeId] = tt.[TransactionTypeId]
    INNER JOIN dbo.[Product] p ON i.[ProductId] = p.[ProductId]
GO
```

Looking at the output of the view:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.[Inventory_Balances] ib
ORDER BY ib.[ProductName]
    , ib.[TransactionDate]
```

| ProductName | TransactionDate | Transaction Type | Transaction Quantity | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Acetominophen | 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 +00:00 | Product Received | 12 | 12 |
| Acetominophen | 2021-10-08 19:26:01.329 +00:00 | Product Assigned to Patient | -4 | 8 |
| Acetylsalicylic Acid | 2021-01-02 12:34:56.789 +00:00 | Product Received | 6 | 6 |

And a simple query showing the current balance in the custody of each patient:

```
SELECT pa.[PatientName]
    , pr.[ProductName]
    , ppo.TransactionDate
    , [Balance] = SUM(ppo.Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY ppo.[PatientId], ppo.[ProductId] ORDER BY ppo.[TransactionDate] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM dbo.[Patient] pa
    INNER JOIN dbo.[Patient_Product_OnHand] ppo ON pa.[PatientId] = ppo.[PatientId]
    INNER JOIN dbo.[Product] pr ON ppo.[ProductId] = pr.[ProductId];
```

| PatientName | ProductName | TransactionDate | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sally | Acetominophen | 2021-10-08 19:26:01.329 +00:00 | 4 |

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you should create a cross-reference table (XRef) that links a patient to inventory.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/how-do-i-create-a-cross-reference-table-query-for-my-data

Comment: Just FYI, I did not downvote your answer.  Having said that, link-only answers are frowned upon here, even if they point to [so].